# When setting the pointer to nil, struct pointer field doesn't change

Tags: go, pointers

I have this code:

```
type X struct {
    y *X
}

func main() {
    x1 := &X{y: nil}
    x2 := &X{y: x1}

    fmt.Println(x1 == x2.y)
    // true

    x1 = nil

    fmt.Println(x1 == nil)
    fmt.Println(x2.y == nil)

    // true
    // false
}
```

As you can see `x.y` is a `*X`.
Why after setting `x1` to `nil`. The value of `x2.y` doesn't become `nil`?
Sorry if my question is so silly.

Here is the [link](https://go.dev/play/p/O0ZRf9DqeNz) of the code in Go playground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x1` is a pointer pointing to an `{y:nil}` of type `X`.
`x2.y` is also a pointer pointing to the same `{y:nil`}. So when you set `x1=nil`, `x1` becomes a pointer that is nil, and `x2.y` is still pointing to the same `{y:nil}` object.

Answer (score 1):

No, `x2.y` will still point to the object you assigned to `x1`. This is what your code is basically doing:

```
Objects in memory
| memory address | value             | 
| 0xDEADBEEF     | X{y: nil }        |
| 0x1BADB002     | X{y: 0xDEADBEEF } |
|----------------|-------------------|

In your code:
| variable     | value      |
| x1           | 0xDEADBEEF |
| x2           | 0x1BADB002 |
```

So now by doing `x1 = nil`, all you do is changing the value of a variable:

```
| variable     | value      |
| x1           | nil        |
| x2           | 0x1BADB002 |
```

`x2` still points to a value in memory, which in turn points to another object in memory. The go runtime recognises this, and sees that the object stored in `0xDEADBEEF` is still in use, so it doesn't release the memory.

A more visual representation would be something like this:

```
+-----------+(0xDEADBEEF)
| X{y: nil} |
+-----------+
  /\       /\
  ||-------||--> Both point to the same object
 +----+    ||
 | x1 |    ||
 +----+    ||
+----------||------+(0x1BADB002)
| X{y: 0xDEADBEEF} |
+------------------+
  /\
  || points to this object
 +----+
 | x2 |
 +----+
```

By setting `x1 = nil`, all you've done is severed the link between the variable `x1` and the actual object in memory. The link between `x2.y` and that object still exists.